# tail random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\{X_1,X_2,\dots \}$ be a sequence of random variables.

Let $b_n > 0$ be a sequence of positive real numbers which increase monotonically to $\infty$

Then, for each $n$, define $$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n {X_i}$$

Then, why is $$Z = \limsup\dfrac{S_n}{b_n}$$ a tail random variable in the sense that $Z$ is measurable with respect to $\cap_{n\geq 1} \sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},\dots)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a start, 
$$
{S_n\over b_n}={X_1\over b_n}+{\sum_{k=2}^nX_k\over b_n}.
$$From this and the fact that $\lim_n b_n =\infty$, it follows that 
$$
Z=\limsup_{n\to\infty} {\sum_{k=2}^n X_k\over b_n},
$$
which shows that $Z$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(X_2,X_2,\ldots)$.

[Added detail: I used above a little lemma from analysis, to the effect that if we have three real sequences related by $A_n = B_n+C_n$ and if $B:=\lim_n B_n$ exists, then $\limsup_n A_n = B+\limsup_nC_n$. In the preceding paragraph, take $A_n=S_n(\omega)/b_n$, $B_n=X_1(\omega)/b_n$, and $C_n=(\sum_{k=2}^n X_k(\omega)/b_n$, for a fixed sample point $\omega$.]

Comment: I am having trouble understanding that "from this and the fact that ..., it follows that". Can you give me some details?

Comment: @pm021: I added some detail to my Answer.

Comment: Thanks for filling in the details for me

Answer (score 1):

For every $i$ you get $X_i/b_n\rightarrow 0$ with $n\rightarrow \infty$. So for every $k,m\geq 1$ you get 
$$\sup_{n\geq k}\frac{X_1+\dots+X_n}{b_n}=\sup_{n\geq k}\frac{X_m+\dots+X_n}{b_n}$$
And so for every $m\geq 1$ you get
$$\limsup \frac{S_n}{b_n}=\limsup \frac{X_m+\dots+X_n}{b_n}$$
so you get measurability of $\limsup S_n/b_n$ with respect to $\sigma(X_m,X_{m+1},\dots)$ for every $m\geq 1$ and exactly that means measurability with respect to $\cap_{m\geq 1}\sigma(X_m,X_{m+1},\dots)$.